# Doctype breaks jquery fadeOut method in IE!

Tags: jquery, html, doctype

I recently added a doctype to my page to help fix a little IE rendering problem. It looks like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

My fadeOut code (I'm using `stop(true,true)` to restart the animation if its in progress):

```
$('#myElement').stop(true, true).show().fadeOut(5000);
```

Now, my jquery `fadeOut(5000)` method doesn't fade in IE anymore. Does anyone know of a fix for this?

**EDIT:**
I've tried pretty much every flavor of DOCTYPE out there, and no matter which one I use, the fadeOut animation does NOT work in IE.

Comment: **Off-topic**, but if your only reason for adding the DOCTYPE was to fix a little IE rendering problem, I wouldn't use HTML4 strict, unless your HTML will [validate](http://validator.w3.org) in HTML4 strict. If you're just trying to kick the browser into standards mode (a Good Thing(tm)), I'd go with the new HTML5 DOCTYPE (`<!DOCTYPE html>`). Still kicks it into standards mode without making promises about HTML4 strict conformity. [More here](http://ejohn.org/blog/html5-doctype/)

Comment: It just makes promises of HTML5 conformity instead - and HTML 5 is a moving target.

Comment: I have the same issue, if i take the doc type out then the jquery scrolling works, put it in and it doesnt work. Problem is that if you take out the doc type then IE runs it in Quirks mode which means it messes it all up. Still havent found an answer :-(

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried another Doctype, like transitional or xhtml?

Answer (score 0):

i think that its not about doctype. All ie versions always having troubles with fade animations.